# Issue with CONVERT()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do a CONVERT() excel formula to convert feet and inches to metres and I am trying to use the CONVERT formula.

```
=(CONVERT(G17,"ft","m"))+(CONVERT(H17,"in","m"))
```

[image]

The ft part of the equation works but the in does not, can anyone explain my mistake?

Comment: Is this Excel, Google Sheets, or both? Make sure you use the proper tags.

Comment: 12 in = 0.3048 m. Are you displaying enough decimal places?

Comment: Try a custom number format of `General \m`

Comment: This is Excel, my apologies, I didn't mean to click google Speadsheets.. Removing

Answer (score 0):

Jeeped was correct, my formula was fine but my decimal place was too short for an answer.